# algorithm - least amount of time spent to yield the greatest amount of MB

Tags: algorithm, formula

I have:

- a lot of folders
  -- folders have video files
  -- in the folders there are video files are varying length

Data Set

- tCount = Number of files in folders
- tTotalTime = Total Duriation of all video files in a folder
- tSize = Total Size of the folder

I have a bunch of video files in folders.  I want to rank what I folder contents I should watch based:

- largest folder size
- least amount of time to watch.

I can't seem to get the algorithm to do this.

any help would be appreciated on the formula to do this.

edit: clarifying more accurately
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what seems to work for me is
(tSize/tCount)/tTotalTime = value

value is ranked from descending. high to lowest

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a greedy property: delete the folders based on their `size/time` values. (Easy to prove the correctness of this greedy property).
Sort all folders based on descending `size/time` values. Start deleting the folders till the required amount of space isn't freed.

Comment: Thanks for the response I greatly appreciate it.